# Font of word document

Tags: java, docx4j

Is it possible to set the font size without referring to paragraph. Is there any possible method to select all in the word document and change the font size and the font type in one shot while using the jar `docx4j`.

```
WordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addStyledParagraphOfText("Subtitle","Arial");
```

This always adds the paragraph and then sets the font. I don't want this since I am not adding any paragraph. I am reading a text file and want to write the same in word document. The problem is that by default the font size for the document written comes up as 12 and with Arial font. So the lines go off to the next lines and indentation gets problematic.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The place to do this is in the rPrDefault in the styles part.  For example:

```
<w:styles xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:docDefaults>
    <w:rPrDefault>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial" w:eastAsia="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:ascii="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
      </w:rPr>
    </w:rPrDefault>
```

w:sz is font size, in half points.

To manipulate your styles part, use WordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getStyleDefinitionsPart().getContents()

To add a paragraph with no properties, use getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText, or create a P p = new P(); then add your contents, then add it to the MainDocumentPart's contents.

Comment: Could you please advice where can i add this.